# Iterating through input-scenarios and storing results as nested arrays in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to run my model for all 3 input-scenarios using a loop instead of having to copy paste the script 3 times and changing the input-data manually. I have 3 arrays of input-data and would like to store the results (also arrays of the same length) in separate nested arrays within the same variable. Currently, I only know how to append the results. However, it is incorrect and I want to store the results for the different scenario-runs in separate elements within the same variable.

```
import numpy as np
# Scenarios
years = np.arange(50)
sc0 = np.arange(50)
sc1 = np.arange(50)+100
sc2 = np.arange(50)+200

scenarios = [sc0, sc1, sc2]

results = [] 

# Model computes something
for sc in range(3):
    for t in years:
        outcome = scenarios[sc][t] / 10
        results.append(outcome)
```

In a nutshell, the solution should allow me to access the results for all model runs using `results[0]`, `results[1]`, and `results[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new list, `subresults`, which is created as `[]` for each scenario. Then this is appended to the list `results` after every outcome has been calculated for that scenario.

```
import numpy as np
# Scenarios
years = np.arange(50)
sc0 = np.arange(50)
sc1 = np.arange(50)+100
sc2 = np.arange(50)+200

scenarios = [sc0, sc1, sc2]

results = []

# Model computes something
for sc in range(3):
    subresults = [] 
    for t in years:
        outcome = scenarios[sc][t] / 10
        subresults.append(outcome)
    results.append(subresults)
```

Then you access your results using `results[0]`, `results[1]`, and `results[2]`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! If I am not mistaking you need to change either "resultssets" or "results.append" in your answer for the solution to run out of the box.

Comment: Oops! Fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

Comprehension will do it as well:

```
resultsets = [[sc[t]/10 for t in years] for sc in scenarios]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! The actual model is quite a bit longer so comprehension was deemed too difficult to read by my supervisor.

Comment: @Kevin Okay, I'll leave it here if someone finds similar problem to yours.